# OS X: destroyfvkeyonstandby question

Tags: osx

*This is a very OS X specific question. I don't know if it applies to the rest of the Unix family. Sorry if this isn't the best forum for it, but the users here appear to be more knowledgeable in general than the superuser forum, and this is a tough question.*

[2014 rMBP, OS X 10.9.5, FileVault 2 whole disk encryption]

I enabled `destroyfvkeyonstandby`, which was confirmed with `pmset -g`. Previously, the computer would sleep, go into standby, and recover fine, with my having to enter a user account pw.

From the man page and various posts, I expected the same behavior, but wasn't sure whether I would have to enter a pw twice. Instead, the computer went into sleep mode properly, but I don't know whether it entered standby; it seems to have powered off.

When I lifted the lid this morning, pressing keys had no effect. I had to press the power button, and then it made the self-test sound and opened to the initial power-on screen.

#### Questions

- Why?
- What happened?
- Why did the machine power itself off?
- Other than the negligible extra time, should I even care?

Comment: Yes, OSX questions are [on topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as long as they are about the UNIX side of OSX and not the GUI functions. Your other alternatives include [su] and [apple.se].

Comment: I suspect you're more likely to find someone knowledgeable about this level of OS X arcana at apple.stackexchange.com.